# How to get the pharmacodynamics data using lixoft connectors (Monolix) and getChartsData()?

Tags: r, connector, vpc

I built a pharmacokietics/pharmacodynamics (PK/PD) model with Monolix and I'm using R to plot the results.
As suggested in Monolix website and on CRAN, I linked R and Monolix, loaded my project and retreived the data. I am stuck at this step.

```
library(lixoftConnectors) # to connect R and Monolix
initializeLixoftConnectors(software="monolix") # makes the link to the MonolixSuite installation

loadProject("~/pkpd.mlxtran") # to load the project

data <- getChartsData(plotName = "plotVpc") # to get the data
```

At this point, data contains only the PK data and not the PD. I tried other models, other plots but the problem is the same, I can plot all the PK but not the PD (since there is no data). In Monolix, I have run the PD also and I have the plots.

Thanks a lot!

Have a nice day,
Best,
Carla

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the PD data indicating the obsName = "y2", like the following:

```
data <- getChartsData(computeSettings = list(obsName = "y2"), plotName = "plotVpc") # to get the data
```

The standard is to retrieve the "y1", which is usually the PK data.

Hope this helps!